# Moving back an iteration in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

So I want to do something like this:

```
for i in range(5):
    print(i);
    if(condition==true):
        i=i-1;
```

However, for whatever reason, even though I'm decrementing i, the loop doesn't seem to notice. Is there any way to repeat an iteration?

Comment: do not change the wheels of the car when you moving.

Comment: There are a lot of answers below which explain exactly how to increment `i` in this manner. I'd like to understand what you're doing with `i` as there may be a much clearer way of handling this code.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`for` loops in Python always go forward. If you want to be able to move backwards, you must use a different mechanism, such as `while`:

```
i = 0
while i < 5:
    print(i)
    if condition:
        i=i-1
    i += 1
```

Or even better:

```
i = 0
while i < 5:
    print(i)
    if condition:
        do_something()
        # don't increment here, so we stay on the same value for i
    else:
        # only increment in the case where we're not "moving backwards"
        i += 1
```

Comment: I don't have to like it, I just have to program it

Answer (score 9):

Python loop using `range` are by-design to be different from C/C++/Java `for`-loops. For every iteration, the i is set the the next value of `range(5)`, no matter what you do to `i` in between.

You could use a while-loop instead:

```
i = 0
while i<5:
    print i
    if condition:
        continue
    i+=1
```

But honestly: I'd step back and think again about your original problem. Probably you'll find a better solution as such loops are always error-prone. There's a reason why Python `for`-loops where designed to be different.

Answer (score 5):

You have a misunderstanding about loops in Python.  The `for` loop doesn't care what you do with `i` at each iteration, because it is not related to the logic of the loop at all.  Modifying `i` just rebinds a local variable.

You would need to use a while loop to achieve the behaviour you're expecting, where the state of `i` does affect the control flow of the loop:

```
import random

i = 0
while i < 5:
    print(i)
    i += 1
    if random.choice([True, False]):
        i -= 1
```

Answer (score 3):

`range(5)` creates a list with numbers `0` thru `4` in it - `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`.

When you run a for loop over it, you are iterating over the list. Doing `i-= 1` will only decrement the **value** of that particular element of the list, and the iteration will continue.

Like the other answers here have suggested, you should use a `while` loop.

```
i= 0
while i<5:
    # do stuff
    if #condition:
        i-= 1 # or +
    i+= 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Repeating many other answers, and just for completeness, you will need to use a `while loop`.

```
i = 0
while i < 5:
    print(i)
    if (not condition):
       i+=1
```

If you want to move back an iteration in the loop (instead of repeating an iteration), then use this:

```
i = 0
while i < 5:
    print(i)
    if (condition):
        i -= 1
    else:
        i += 1
```

Essentially, `while i < 5` evaluates upon each iteration, and checks if `i < 5`.  Thus by decrementing/not changing `i`, we get something like this: (values of `i`)

Not changing:  `1->2->3-(condition satisfied)> 3 -> 4 -> 5`

Decrementing: `1->2->3-(condition satisfied)>2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5`

The reason why `i=i-1` in your for loop doesn't make it repeat the iteration is simple.  In the `for` loop, `i` is assigned the value of the next item in the for loop.  Python could care less about what you do with `i`, as long as it is able to assign the next item to it.  Thus, the for loop `for i in <your_iterable>:<do whatever>` is closer to this:

```
_i = 0
_length = len(<your_iterable>)
while _i < _length:
    i = _i
    _i += 1
    <do whatever>
```

However, in this analogy, you wouldn't be able to access the `_` predicated variables (`_i`,`_length`).  This is how I simplify the logic of the `for loop`.  Note that regardless of what `i` is assigned to, it will be assigned to `_i` upon the next iteration, and the loop really doesn't care about what `i` is.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize a `while` loop:

```
i = 0
while i < 5:
    print(i)
    if condition:
        i -= 1
    i += 1
```

As has been mentioned, this is rather unidiomatic Python. Perhaps if you post what you are trying to achieve we can give some better advice.

Comment: What happens to `i` if the condition is always true?

Comment: You're in an infinite loop

Answer (score 1):

In Python it's possible to set up a two-way exchange between an iterator (what comes after `in` in a `for..in` loop) and its consumer (code inside the loop). To achieve this, you can use [`send`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-iterator-methods) in the consumer code to "inject" a value in a generator. In your case, you can simply send back the current value once the condition is met and wrap the `range` call in a generator that repeats whatever is sent back to it. Here's some code for you to play, intentionally verbose for clarity:

```
def repeateble(it):
    buf, it = None, iter(it)
    while True:
        if buf is None:
            # the buffer is empty, send them the next elem
            val = next(it)
        else:
            # there's something in the buffer
            # let's send that back
            val = buf

        # send the value and wait what they say
        back = yield val

        if back:
            # they've sent us something!
            # give them some dummy value as a result of send()
            yield None 
            # and save what they've sent in a buffer
            # for the next iteration
            buf = back

        else:
            # they haven't sent anything
            # empty the buffer
            buf = None


from random import randint

# create a repeateble generator
rng = repeateble(range(100))

for x in rng:
    print(x)

    # check "some condition"...
    if randint(1, 100) > 80:
        print('repeat:')
        # send the current value back to the generator
        # it will be returned on the next iteration
        rng.send(x)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use readlines if you're iterating through a file and pull out the previous lines based on a condition.

```
with open("myfile.txt", "r") as f:
    text = f.readlines()
    for row in range(0, len(text)):
        if re.search("Error", text[row]):
            print(text[row-1].strip())
```