# copy files based on choice of plot

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, matplotlib, operating-system

i have many .txt files in a directory.At first i want to plot the files one by one on the screen and if it looks fine then i want to copy the .txt file to a directory called "test_folder".
If it doesnot looks fine then i donot want to copy the .txt file to the "test_folder" directory.

I tried the below script, however i couldn't do that as i am new to python. I hope experts may help me overcoming this problem.Thanks in advance.

```
import numpy as np
import os,glob,shutil
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

os.mkdir('test_folder')

for filex in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    print(filex)
    data=np.loadtxt(filex)
    plt.plot(data)
    plt.show()

    if plot_looks_nice == "yes": 
    #copy the filex to the directory "test_folder"
       shutil.copy(filex,'test_folder')
    elif plot_looks_nice == "no": 
    #donot copy the filex to the directory "test_folder"
         print("not copying files as no option chosen")
    else: 
    print("Please enter yes or no.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty close. You want to use `input()` to prompt the user and get a variable back with their input.

The best way to make a directory is to use pathlib (python >= 3.5) to recursively create directories if they don't exist. This way you never have to worry about errors due to directories not existing

See modified code below.

```
import numpy as np
import os,glob,shutil
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pathlib import Path

Path("test_folder").mkdir(exist_ok=True)

for filex in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    print(filex)
    data=np.loadtxt(filex)
    plt.plot(data)
    plt.show()

    plot_looks_nice = input('Looks good? ')

    if plot_looks_nice == "y": #use single letters to make your work faster
    #copy the filex to the directory "test_folder"
       shutil.copy(filex,'test_folder')
    elif plot_looks_nice == "n": 
    #donot copy the filex to the directory "test_folder"
         print("not copying files as no option chosen")
    else: 
    print("Please enter \'y\' or \'n\'.")
```

Comment: Note that as it stands your code will do nothing to a file if the user doesn't enter a correct response as it will just move onto the next file. This may or may not be okay for what you are doing but it is something to consider.

Comment: can it be modified little bit if directory exist it shows error can this portion be done automatic

Comment: Sure. Instead of an error, I have added code that will just make the directory if it doesn't exist. I find this is better than just chucking an error.

Comment: i want to go back to see previous plot at this time its not working, can this be implemented in one line

Comment: Not easily. For loops can't do that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374181/moving-back-an-iteration-in-a-for-loop